# Passing path arguments to a form builder

Tags: forms, 8, routes

I'm trying to understand how to port the following D7 code to Drupal 8.

```
function x_menu() {
    $menu['x/form/test/%/%'] = [
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => ['x_form_test', 3, 4],
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
        'title' => 'Test Form',
    ];
    return $menu;
}


function x_form_test(&$form, $form_state, $arg1, $arg2) {
    return $form;
}
```

From what I can glean from the documentation of the Routing and Form API, the new way to connect a path to a form is to put this in `x.routing.yml`:

```
x.form_test:
    path: 'x/form/{arg1}/{arg2}',
    defaults:
        _form: '\Drupal\x\XFormTest'
        _title: 'Test Form'
```

and then create a form class `XFormTest` that ultimately descends from `FormBase`.

However, it's clearly impossible* to add extra arguments to an inherited function signature like `public FormInterface::buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`

How can I read `$arg1` and `$arg2` in `XFormTest::buildForm()`, preferably while still pointing the route at the form rather than putting a Controller around it?

(Routing API: https://www.drupal.org/node/2092643)

*Update: Maybe it's not so much impossible as that I'm not doing it correctly.

My function declaration

```
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

class XBBCodeHandlerForm extends FormBase {
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $format = XBBCODE_GLOBAL) {
  }
}
```

generates the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Drupal\xbbcode\Form\XBBCodeHandlerForm::buildForm() 
must be compatible with 
Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm(array $form, 
Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state)
 in /home/arancaytar/software/web/drupal/modules/xbbcode/src/Form/XBBCodeHandlerForm.php
on line 161
```

Edit: I misunderstood the fatal error; it wasn't caused by the extra argument but by changing the value argument $form_state to a reference argument. PHP does allow adding optional arguments to overriding functions, apparently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's clearly impossible to add extra arguments to an inherited function signature

Not true - adding extra arguments to a function signature is one of the fundamental reasons that inheritance exists in OO.

You literally just need to add your arguments to the function signature to make this work:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $arg1, $arg2) {
    // You have $arg1 and $arg2 available
}
```

You could do something more fancy and get typed data by using [parameter upcasting](https://www.drupal.org/node/2122223), otherwise you'll get the args as strings.

[Examples here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310425).

Comment: I must be doing it wrong somehow, because I'm getting this error:

    `Declaration of Drupal\xbbcode\Form\XBBCodeHandlerForm::buildForm() must be compatible with Drupal\Core\Form\FormInterface::buildForm(array $form, Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) in /home/arancaytar/software/web/drupal/modules/xbbcode/src/Form/XBBCodeHandlerForm.php on line 161`


My function declaration is:

`public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface &$form_state, $format = XBBCODE_GLOBAL)`

Comment: What is your form class extending? (it should be `FormBase` or a derivative, not an interface)

Comment: I'm extending FormBase (question updated)

Comment: Just in the middle of something sorry, will take a look in a bit

Comment: Oops, I just noticed that I'm taking the form_state as a reference for some reason. If I delete the '&', I don't get the same error anymore.

Comment: Ah yes didn't notice that - reference/value arguments are part of the contract so that makes sense